# How do I get the Presentation Minimizer to work in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: libreoffice

I want to use the Presentation Minimizer tool in LibreOffice, on Natty 64bit. I have the package libreoffice-presentation-minimizer installed (it is enabled by default). In OOo, the minimizer tool appeared in the Tools menu, but I cannot find the option there.

Comment: It's still there on Natty 32 bits, 6th option in the Tools menu. Maybe it's a 64bits issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to manually add the [Sun Presentation Minimizer](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/PresentationMinimizer) (from Open Office) e.g. with *Tools -> Extension Manager*.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with LO 3.5:
"Loading component library failed"
Any idea why?

Comment: @chtfn: doesn't the [libreoffice-presentation-minimizer](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/extensions/) work in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install separate extensions as of LibreOffice 3.3.

As seen in the [release notes](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/extensions/), the minimizer extension is now included in the main program.